# .Net 4.5 WCF Azure AD B2C SOA

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity, azure-ad-b2c

We're looking to rewrite an existing solution into the cloud using all things new.

Ideally, the architecture we would like would be an MVC5 front end built on SOA against a WCF Service.

In terms of securing the MVC front end and WCF service; we would like to use Azure AD B2C if this is possible. Therefore the user would log into the MVC front end and this would pass relevant claims up to a claims aware WCF service.

Could somebody confirm whether this is possible, and if so, point towards some literature which details the configuration of a claims aware WCF service using AD B2C? We have managed to set up an MVC solution using Azure AD B2C, however cannot find the equivalent for configuring the WCF Service.